# 'Error: redirect_uri_mismatch' in Googe AdWords integration

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, integration, google-ads-api

I am using XAMPP for Linux 5.6.30

I want to integrate 'Google Adwords API' in my project for display campaigns details.

I create new project in developer console with help of this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project)
for 'Web client' and define **Authorized JavaScript origins:**http://localhost AND **Authorized redirect URIs:**https://localhost/googleads/

Also try **Authorized JavaScript origins:**http://report.myproject.com AND **Authorized redirect URIs:**http://report.myproject.com/googleads

I also **refer some solutions on StackOverflow** which discuss previously but I can't get a solution .

When i run `PHP GetRefreshToken.php' in the terminal, it generates one URL but when i open that URL is displayed error 'Error: redirect_uri_mismatch' with this message 'The redirect URI in the request,xxx.xxx.xxx can only be used by a Client ID for a native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type.'

I also have developerToken and clientCustomerId of Google Adwords account.

**Is am i doing right way or not?**

**is google adwords integration works in localhost server or i have to put it on my live server?**

My project is already on live server i just integrate adwords api in local server

Comment: You should put some code

Comment: Thank you for the response, but first, i am confused about to set above two highlighted URL.when i get an idea about this then i am able to paste my code here.@LeandroRodrigues

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to below documentation.

### [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app)

Example for end-to-end OAuth2 using php is Given here.

#### Create authorization credentials

Any application that uses OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs must have authorization credentials that identify the application to Google's OAuth 2.0 server. The following steps explain how to create credentials for your project. Your applications can then use the credentials to access APIs that you have enabled for that project.

1. Open the Credentials page in the API Console.
2. Click **Create credentials > OAuth client ID**.
3. Complete the form. Set the application type to `Web application`. Applications that use languages and frameworks like PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, and .NET must specify authorized **redirect URI**s. The redirect URIs are the endpoints to which the OAuth 2.0 server can send responses. For testing, you can specify URIs that refer to the local machine, such as `http://localhost:8080`.

Google recommends that you [design your app's auth endpoints](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#protectauthcode) so that your application does not expose authorization codes to other resources on the page.